# Swift - Convert to absolute value

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

is there any way to get absolute value from an integer?
for example

```
-8  
to  
 8
```

I already tried to use UInt() assuming it will convert the Int to unsigned value but it didn't work.

Comment: cast/convert should never used to change value

Answer (score 450, accepted):

The standard `abs()` function works great here:

```
let c = -8
print(abs(c))
// 8
```

Comment: What needs to be imported to use abs()?

Comment: @JarrodSmith: import Foundation

Comment: You can either import Darwin or Foundation

Comment: Isn't Darwin part of Foundation?

Comment: it won't work for `Int8(-128)` - this will cause `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`

Comment: @derpoliuk This is expected. See [Apple’s explanation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2885649-abs).

Answer (score 57):

With Swift 5, you may use one of the two following ways in order to convert an integer to its absolute value.

---

### #1. Get absolute value of an `Int` from `magnitude` property

`Int` has a [`magnitude`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/2886869-magnitude) property. `magnitude` has the following declaration:

```
var magnitude: UInt { get }
```

> For any numeric value `x`, `x.magnitude` is the absolute value of `x`.

The following code snippet shows how to use `magnitude` property in order to get the absolute value on an `Int` instance:

```
let value = -5
print(value.magnitude) // prints: 5
```

---

### #2. Get absolute value of an `Int` from `abs(_:)` method

Swift has a global numeric function called [`abs(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2885649-abs) method. `abs(_:)` has the following declaration:

```
func abs<T>(_ x: T) -> T where T : Comparable, T : SignedNumeric
```

> Returns the absolute value of the given number.

The following code snippet shows how to use `abs(_:)` global function in order to get the absolute value on an `Int` instance:

```
let value = -5
print(abs(value)) // prints: 5
```

Comment: print(abs(Int.min)) won't work. Is there any solution for Swift 3? I haven't updated my project yet.

Comment: Missed opportunity to say *"get the absolute value on an **Int**stance"*

Comment: @bibscy See [Apple's explanation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2885649-abs) to understand why `abs(Int8.min)` can't work and therefore creates an overflow error.

Answer (score 21):

If you want to force a number to change or keep it positive.
Here is the way:

```
abs() for int
fabs() for double
fabsf() for float
```

Comment: fabs is deprecated

Comment: @ChewieTheChorkie fabs(Double), fabs(Float) and fabs(Float80) are not deprecated. What is deprecated is fabs(FloatingPoint) which was renamed to abs() instead

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get absolute value from a double or Int, use `fabs` func:

```
var c = -12.09
print(fabs(c)) // 12.09
c = -6
print(fabs(c)) // 6
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, but my focus was on `fabs`, excuse me